# Shorten comment per rows in div

Tags: javascript

I want to shorten comments with long text and add a "... [show full post]" behind the cut text to expand the full post.
Since long comments on my site usually are lists it may be best to cut them after e.g. 5 rows inside the comment div, but without breaking the html, i.e. the p tag.

```
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
    body {font-family:sans-serif; font-size:0.8em}
    .comments {border:1px solid #aaa; padding:5px; margin-bottom:10px}
    .commenttop {background-color:#f9f9f9; padding:5px}
    .username {float:left; margin-right:10px; font-weight:bold}
    .commentpost {padding:0 5px}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="comments">
<div class="commenttop"><div class="username">User 1</div>
<div class="date">12:12, 28 October 2010 (CEST)</div></div>
<div class="commentpost">
<p>Very long comment here<br />
<br />
Text in row 3<br />
Text in row 4<br />
Text in row 5<br />
Text in row 6<br />
Text in row 7<br />
Text in row 8<br />
Text in row 9<br />
Text in row 10<br />
Text in row 11<br />
Text in row 12
</p>
</div></div>

<div class="comments">
<div class="commenttop"><div class="username">User 2</div>
<div class="date">17:22, 30 October 2010 (CEST)</div></div>
<div class="commentpost">
<p>Text in row 1<br />
Text in row 2
</p>
</div></div>


</body>
</html>
```

In this example the result should be

---

Very long comment here

Text in row 3
Text in row 4
Text in row 5 ... show full post

---

Any idea how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `overflow` attribute of CSS and then check in Javascript, if the shown height equals the defined `max-height` and show the link.

Comment: This might be the easiest solution yeah. Thanks for all the ideas :)

Comment: I'm sorry, but the simpliest solution is often the best. Of course I should have come up with that idea myself but I didn't think of it and started from the complicated direction (javascript solution). And how should a new user have 100% acceptance?

Answer (score 0):

If you set the css `line-height` property of div.commentpost p  you will know how tall each line is. You can then set the `height` of commentpost p  to to be the `number of lines you want to see * lineheight` and set `overflow:hidden` and add a link with a clickhandler that toggles the overflow.

Here's some psuedocode:

```
For Each div.commentpost => x
     if x.height > (max#lines * lineheight)
           x.height = (max#lines*lineheight)
           x.overflow = hidden
           x.insertAfter (new div(y))
           y.contents = a.link(onClick: (toggle(overflow.visible/overflow.hidden))
      end if
next div
```

It would be easiest if done in jQuery I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can add an ellipsis without JavaScript, just CSS, by setting `text-overflow: ellipsis;` Works in all modern browsers except Firefox due to a [bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=312156).